# a:hover not working inside <span>

Tags: html, css, anchor

i  am writing some basic html code where there is a `span tag inside anchor tag` like this

```
<a href="#">
   <span class="link">  Shipping info  </span>
 </a>
```

when i do  `a:hover {color:#F07DE0;}` that does not work , can any one guide me about it which selector should i  use to  achive  hover effect  ?

Comment: Have you tried `a:hover span {color:#F07DE0;}`?

Comment: infect this is email template so i was not sure it its  going to work

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Do you have other CSS styles applied to the `<span>`?

Comment: Its worth a shot and if that doesn't work, try to place it below your `span.link` selector in the code.

Comment: @showdev he does have styles because it has a class

Comment: @Sinomai Having a class doesn't mean it has CSS definitions. We'll need to see more of the OPs code to know for sure.

Comment: @showdev its enough to imply since thats what is probably causing the problem

Comment: @Sinomai Yes, I agree that is most likely the cause of the problem. But speculation can introduce more problems, so its best to ask. That's why "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself." Methodical debugging helps people understand what is going wrong, rather than just what code happens to fix it.

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers? Maybe only Firefox? Is anybody else seeing it or not in its browser?

Comment: his problem (my assumption from the code) is he has the `span.link` css giving a color to the text in the span, because he is trying to use css for the `a:hover`  the `span.link` is overriding the css, as its defined and would take presedence

Answer (score 1):

Try `a:hover span` or `a span:hover`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x8Zq4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `a:hover span {color:#F07DE0;}` in this case.

http://jsfiddle.net/y3tUH/